# Typescript: Mapping Tuples to Union types doesn't seem work inside nested objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Vue project in Typescript, and I'm running into an issue regarding the mapping of an Object of Tuples to an Object of Union types.

For a bit of context, I'm working on a Backend endpoint's expected response types. Currently, this endpoint receives 2 values: an enum, and a string. Depending on the enum the response object will change.

This is the current implementation:

```js
const validations = {
  email: ['isValid', 'isAvaliable'],
  password: ['isMinLengthValid', 'hasUppercase', 'hasLowercase', 'hasSpecialChars', 'hasNumbers'],
  iban: ['isValid', 'isRegistered']
} as const

type ValidationsMap = {
  [T in keyof typeof validations]: typeof validations[T][number]
}

function validate<T extends keyof ValidationsMap>(type: T, value: string): Record<ValidationsMap[T], boolean> {
  // Do something
}
```

Now the Backend endpoint will receive one more parameter, and the response object will depend on it too.

This is what I've tried, but it's not working:

```js
const validations = {
  portal: {
    email: ['isValid', 'isAvaliable'],
    password: ['isMinLengthValid', 'hasUppercase', 'hasLowercase', 'hasSpecialChars', 'hasNumbers'],
  },
  payment: {
    email: ['isValid'],
    iban: ['isValid', 'isRegistered']
  }
} as const

type ValidationsMap = {
  [S in keyof typeof validations]: {
    [T in keyof typeof validations[S]]: typeof validations[S][T][number] // Error: Type 'number' cannot be used to index type...
  }
}

function validate<S extends keyof ValidationsMap, T extends keyof ValidationsMap[S]>(service: S, type: T, value: string): Record<ValidationsMap[S][T], boolean> {
  // Do something
}
```

Does anyone know why this doesn’t work?

I thought there might be a limit to how deep it will allow to map a Tuple to a Union, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

This works correctly:

```js
type PortalEmailValidation = typeof validations['portal']['email'][number]
```

Comment: I'd say this is due to a TS bug, [ms/TS#27709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709), which doesn't seem like it will be fixed anytime soon.  Workarounds involve a sort of redundant constraint, like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4OBAm) shows.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#27709](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27709).  The type checker apparently doesn't properly track the constraints for deep [index access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) types when the keys are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). That issue has been open for a long time with no sign of progress, so for now all we can do is work around it.

---

One approach when the compiler won't accept an index access of the form `T[K]` is to use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), like `T extends Record<K, infer V> ? V : never` (using the [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)). If `K` is a (non-optional) key of `T`, then `T` will be seen as a `Record<K, V>` for some `V`, which we infer.

So instead of `typeof validations[S][T][number]`, we can write `typeof validations[S][T] extends Record<number, infer V> ? V : never`.  Or equivalently:

```
type ValidationsMap = {
  [S in keyof typeof validations]: {
    [T in keyof typeof validations[S]]:
    typeof validations[S][T] extends { [k: number]: infer V } ? V : never
  }
}
```

---

Another approach is to explicitly add back in the missing constraint.  If you have a type `A` that *you* know is assignable to another type `B` but the compiler doesn't know this, then you can replace `A` with `Extract<A, B>` (using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)) and the compiler will accept it.  It knows `Extract<A, B>` is assignable to `B`.  And assuming you're right about `A` being assignable to `B`, then `Extract<A, B>` will evaluate to just `A`.

So if `ValidationsMap[S][T]` is assignable to `string` but the compiler can't see it, we can write `Extract<ValidationsMap[S][T], string>` instead:

```
function validate<S extends keyof ValidationsMap, T extends keyof ValidationsMap[S]>(
  service: S, type: T, value: string
): Record<Extract<ValidationsMap[S][T], string>, boolean> { // okay
  return null!
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYEsAmCovBGBeGAbwFgAoGGABxACcpkAuIsiigUwFsEUkmBtAOQoIANWToBAGhhCIAQUSoEAIyRsBAXUktWlBBAgB3Wmn6yAsijAAZNmADmUABZjUaKTKf6AqpUpsaYH11aQEvCGsQQwCgiBDPfQBlf2AUZABhLxoIDzD9ADkAVw5lAJytHQBfbXIqBABPDjsoJhJa9i4eM2FXCQr2mBRlBDBu0XF3UOEAJTZ7YSgAtncNKrJKmH0YUEgoMjIoev8YXowsHHMESnxmWr5EwbAYAGs2epAAMxhD-0-4Ccw2EgGlaOgofAAKo8Xm8-j82H9FOhATh7hoQWDvkcEV8kWcgRA0ZCNDA2AAPRZgNC4QgwPjPJhgYqlGggx4fAInGAbAD8XMZbDgATWpEq+1IAHoAFRY46nFGQS7XAhtVgwGhsBBocBIepUWj0Xi3NVqjVanV6zjcI0AIh6ExtMAAPjA7fIkSo1DaANyY02a7VgXV1AzGGimV3CSw2OyOFwO52u8K+fyBYKOl028KRaJpuIZpNJFJpJCZBDZAtZgrMso+zGVX0DM2B4N6RrNUEDf3moOWzq2+1uOtd1jNi2DYajSPjIeJt2zebQJZoYdqhvrGBSiXij6FMDAc5PPGYNgAHge5Mp1Jh7y+8sPECV0ihl7s19et5OAIfSrRAD4AAodDiGg4BQYA2CYRJpHhJgIWkRRCkgmBoBoKx7DIABKJhZlAcNTwAUQpGgEAPU97wJX9Eg0YlpFQ9C-2kZQQBANQRj-IgYAlCUYBAZ4Gh0DUoEKGgniZJAkAAQnWIA)